# How to convert Android SingleLaunchActivityTestCase to ActivityTestRule? (Instrumentation unit test)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-testing, android-instrumentation

The documentation for [`SingleLaunchActivityTestCase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/SingleLaunchActivityTestCase) says that this class is now deprecated, and it should be replaced with [`ActivityScenarioRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule) or [`ActivityTestRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule). But how is this done?

`SingleLaunchActivityTestCase` allowed an Activity to launch once and keep it open; then multiple tests can run during this time, then the Activity is closed. `ActivityTestRule` does not seem to have this functionality - it always relaunches the Activity for each `@Test` method.

So is it possible to make `ActivityTestRule` launch an Activity once and keep it open, and how do I ensure the `context` (from `activityTestRule.getActivity()`) is not null for each `@Test` function?

Example code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [constructor that does not start the activity by default](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#ActivityTestRule(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20boolean,%20boolean)) (setting the `launchActivity` argument to `false`). Then use [`launchActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#launchactivity) in your setup, but not in each test method. This way you will start it up once yourself, but each test will operate on the same instance.

You'll probably want to also explicitly finish the activity at the end of the test class, for cleanup.

Note: This isn't generally a best practice for testing though, since tests could depend on each other (which isn't a good idea), or provide incorrect results depending on the order they run, etc. since the activity state is persisted from one test to the next in this case.

Comment: As of September 2020, there is a new class called `ActivityScenarioRule`, which is supposed to replace `ActivityTestRule`. It could potentially make this technique easier. More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule

Answer (score 1):

I used Jon Adams answer to elaborate with an example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class KeepActivityOpenDuringTests {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> activityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class, true, false);

    /**
     * When running the class as a test suite, setUp() is called repeatedly
     * for each test method. Use setupDone to prevent multiple setups.
     */
    private static boolean setupDone;
    // Static to persist across multiple tests
    private static Context context;
    private static MyActivity activityUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Launch the Activity manually, once, to get a real Context object.
        if (!setupDone) {
            activityUnderTest = activityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
            context = (Context) activityUnderTest;
            // continue setup of singletons...
            setupDone = true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // Use context ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
       // Use activityUnderTest ...
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanUp() throws Exception {
        if (activityUnderTest != null) {
            activityUnderTest.finish();
            // Prevent any potential memory leaks
            activityUnderTest = null;
            context = null;
            setupDone = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It works like SingleLaunchActivityTestCase, when the tests are run as a class or individually.

Comment: Note that this kind of test only works if tests run synchronously and not in parallel, or you'd get possibly double setup and/or inconsistent activity state. To be clear, this code does accomplish what the op is asking, but again, as noted above, this is generally a bad testing practice to follow.

Comment: would it be cleaner to use `BeforeClass` instead of a checking a non-synchronized static initialized toggle?

Comment: @JonAdams Useful feedback, thanks. Maybe I'm wrong, but is it really considered bad practice? It's useful for testing static methods, like Database access, which needs a real `context` on a real device/emulator. It's more efficient and faster to run tests this way, instead of starting and stopping the `Activity` each time. And it's just replicating the behavior of `SingleLaunchActivityTestCase` anyway.

Comment: probably not the best place for this discussion, but yeah, the quick version is that this is not a great idea because it adds requirements like a fixed test order and synchronous runner, which slows and limits things, and ties the tests to each other because one test might setup (or break) a future test based on what it does or does not do, etc. Makes tests brittle and dependent on each other. Again, it's not _wrong_, just a bad practice. Integration testing in general, is valid though. I'm referring to the practice of sharing an activity and its state across tests as the bad practice.

Comment: Strangely, I find that the `activityUnderTest` is still forcefully `finish()` after `test1()`. The Activity is no longer visible on screen, but the `context` is still alive. There are 2 methods that try to finish the activity after each test: `MonitoringInstrumentation.ActivityFinisher.run()` and `ActivityTestRule.finishActivity()`.