# How to do Sequential Tests with Espresso Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso

So I want to make my Practice test suite sequential, meaning, tests build on top of each other. Currently its restarting the app every time a test finishes, but I would like for the app to remain open.

I've tried using @BeforeAll but its not working, it makes me add JUnit5.4 to the class path and even after I do It still red, meaning It doesn't like it for some reason.

Anyway, I think its the rule, I think the activity is making my tests restart every time each one finishes, id like it to not do that or if there's a different test rule that I can use that doesn't do that then that would be magnificent.

```
class Practice {

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java);

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        onView(withText("Log In With Mobile Code")).perform(click());
        onView(withResourceName("txtMobileAccessCode")).check(matches(withText("Company Code 
        or\nMobile Access Code")));
    }

    @Test
    fun clickOnEnterAccessCode() {
        onView(withResourceName("txtCodeEntry")).perform(typeText("CodeGoesHere"));
    }

    @Test
    fun enterCode() {
        onView(withResourceName("btnCodeSubmit")).perform(click());
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to do it, having your tests depend on one another is a major anti-pattern in automation. It should generally be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I'm trying to do it because it will make my test suite faster, this is actually not uncommon and done in other testing frameworks such as Protractor to improve speed as you cut on the time the browser needs to close and re-open.

Comment: Sounds like you believe you have a good reason for it. I've hopefully provided some help with my answer.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444272/how-to-convert-android-singlelaunchactivitytestcase-to-activitytestrule-instru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using an `ActivityScenarioRule` to drive things; this calls `ActivityScenario.close()` by default at the end of each test, which will reset your app.

Instead, look at controlling the activity's lifecycle yourself by dealing directly with `ActivityScenario`. There will be more overhead, but you'll have much more control over things and be able to *not* call `close()` until you want to.

From the [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing) the syntax you're looking for is the following:

```
val scenario = launchActivity<MainActivity>()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly, I also looked at the link you posted very very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mike Collins, couldn't have done this without you.
This is the end product, with this is possible to make my whole suite sequential I only have to declare scenario in the first test and the rest keep using the activity.

```
 @Before
 fun setUp() {
     val scenario = launchActivity<MainActivity>()
     
     Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Log In With Mobile 
     Code")).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo())
            
     Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Log In With Mobile 
     Code")).perform(ViewActions.click());

     Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withResourceName("txtMobileAccessCode"))
     .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("Company Code or\nMobile 
     Access Code")));
    }
```

And with this I dont even have to use

```
@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRulePractice(MainActivity::class.java);
```

I can leave that out all together

```
class Test1 {
    
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val scenario = launchActivity<MainActivity>()
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Log In With Mobile Code")).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo())
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Log In With Mobile Code")).perform(ViewActions.click());
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withResourceName("txtMobileAccessCode")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("Company Code or\nMobile Access Code")));
    }

    @Test
    fun clickOnEnterAccessCode() {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withResourceName("txtCodeEntry")).perform(ViewActions.typeText("Bluebook"));
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withResourceName("btnCodeSubmit")).perform(ViewActions.click());
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("<b>Network connection unavailable</b><br/>\n" +
                "Please check your network settings and try again.")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    }

    @After
    fun cleanUp() {
        reportHelper.label("Stopping App");
    }
}
```

I might have to put something on the @After but so far its closing everything automatically.